# IntelliJ show Project own Package as "cannot resolve Symbol"

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

there
I know this Question appears often, but no one of the solutions worked for me, so I ask again.
I have a Maven-Project for Dependencies Managment and a package structure de.somehostname.myName and there some Packages like managers, interface etc.
But my problem appears in the Package containing my Name its underlined with the Info "cannot resolve symbol'myName'" Restarting and Invaldiate Chaches dosent helped for me its show its underlined Red again.
I also have set the SourcesPath.
Mabye its important that i have a dependencie using the same package structure up to hostname so its de.hostname and they can be found.
Hope you can understand my Problem and would be Happy if we could solve this Problem

-Hannes

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note that you must not add source paths to the dependencies, otherwise IDE will consider this folder as a library and since it contains .java files and not .class files, resolution will not work (and the directory that is configured as a library is not parsed for the source level dependencies).

Comment: Now I've got a solution from a team-member I have just renamed the Package and renamed it back to the old Package name like from 'myName' to 'test' and then back to 'myName' now its working fine, but give someone knows why this happens  I would be happy for an answer